# Connect by clause to get the top of hierarchy

Tags: oracle, connect-by

I am facing an issue while using the `CONNECT BY` clause in Oracle for finding hierarchical data. Let me give an example: A is my parent part which has child part B and B also has a child part C. When I am using the `CONNECT BY` clause I am able to get all the three levels but I only want the top most level, i.e. A.

Answer (score 9):

Oracle has a [`LEVEL` pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm#i1009261) that you can use:

```
SELECT
  myTable.ID,
  myTable.ParentID
FROM myTable
WHERE LEVEL = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR myTable.ID = myTable.ParentID
```

---

To find a top-level (root) value from any level, precede the column name with the `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` operator:

```
SELECT
  myTable.ID,
  myTable.ParentID,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT myTable.ID AS "Top Level ID"
FROM myTable
CONNECT BY PRIOR myTable.ID = myTable.ParentID
```

Comment: Thanks Gibbs for your reply but will this query work if i have my child records upto 3 levels..how can i find the parent of the child record is the child record is in the level 3.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to get values from the top level of the hierarchy, no matter which level you're on. Please take a look and see if that's what you need.

Comment: thanks a lot gibbs you input was really valuable.now i am facing an new issue while getting the quantity when parent and child are the same i.e A---A having quantity 14 and A---B having quantity 5.i need an output of 14 but i am getting an output as 5 in cnnect by query..please help me out its really urgent..awaiting for your valuable input

Comment: I'll need to see the table and the data to help with this. If you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with the data and your query so far I'll try to help.

Comment: Gibbs thanks once again for you prompt response i have created a table testing with data in SQL Fiddle.I want the original quantity as 14 by using connect by clause. the link is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/783d5/1/0
PARENTPARTID CHILDPART QTY 
A A 14 
A B 5 
B C 4

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not completely sure what you're trying to get for results. Check out [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/783d5/3) to see if it's what you want. I've put some notes in the comments. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Gibbs actually i am wanting to get only top most parentpartid and its quantity which is in this case 'A'  and 14.i want that query which will return me the top most Parentpartid and its quantity.

Answer (score 4):

I am adding this solution for tables with one or multiple trees (hierarchical data).

Starting with one node (row) somewhere in the tree (hierarchical data), wanting to find the top node (root).

The query is taking advantage of the fact that the *ONLY* the top node (root) of a tree don't have a parent, which is a very common attribute of the top node (root) in any tree structure.

```
SELECT
  c.id
FROM 
  node c
WHERE
  c.parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR
  c.parent_id = c.id
START WITH
  c.id = 1059002615
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT myTable.ID AS "Top Level ID"
  FROM myTable
  CONNECT BY PRIOR myTable.ID = myTable.ParentID
)
WHERE myTable.ParentID IS NULL
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.